# Which package in ubuntu contains the header file X11.h?

Tags: ubuntu, x11

Which package in ubuntu contains the header file X11.h?

Answer (score 33):

Generally, if you look for file in packages you have not installed, use `apt-file` (`sudo apt-get install apt-file` if required).

Use it like this:

```
apt-file update
apt-file search X11/Xlib.h
```

PS: sorry for this stupid question but are you sure you're looking for x11.h?

Comment: Or equivalently use http://packages.debian.org/search?suite=squeeze&arch=any&mode=exactfilename&searchon=contents&keywords=X11.h

Comment: And alternatively, you can also use `wajig` with `wajig find-file Xlib.h`

Comment: This is the most helpful and should have been the accepted answer 4-1/2 years ago.

Answer (score 18):

As far as I can tell you'll need to install libx11-dev.

Answer (score 1):

try x-window-system-dev

Answer (score -1):

There is no supported package contain this header file

may be there is no header named x11.h at all or you want the x11/Xlib.h header that can be found on ivtools-dev, libx11-dev, tendra [not amd64], libroot5.18 or z88dk-data